# Is there a way to check if there are any pending fetch requests?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, request, fetch-api

When using the [browser fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), is there a way to check if there are any pending fetch requests programmatically?