# Is there a way in Cypress to check for open requests?

Tags: cypress

#### Cypress Code:

```js
describe("/gradebook/", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.login("username", "password");
    cy.intercept("GET", "/api/**").as("getApi");
    cy.visit("/home/");
    cy.wait("@getApi");
    cy.log("111");
  });

  after(() => {
    cy.intercept("GET", "/api/**").as("getApi2");
    cy.wait("@getApi2");
    cy.log("333");
    cy.logout();
  });

  it("Loads Page Title: Gradebook", () => {
    cy.log("222");
  });
});
```

#### The Problem:

Sometimes it throws an error `undefined: undefined` but it seems random.

#### Output Image (when it fails):

Only thing I can think of is that it's somehow logging out before the `/api/gradebook/scores/` request finishes, which is why it 400s, but don't know how to fix that. It is intercepting the request, so it shouldn't be continuing to the logout until that's finished.

[image]

---

*Note: I found this [Is there a way to check if there are any pending fetch requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722307/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-there-are-any-pending-fetch-requests) but it doesn't have any answers.